# Data type mismatch while loading mat files (.mat) using `scipy.io` python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, double, mat-file

For a {1x1} struct where the field name is of size {5x1 `**double**`} packed 
inside a mat-file, when i try to read the data type using `dtype`:

```
   import scipy.io as sio 
   a = sio.loadmat('a.mat')
   a['mat_struct_name']['mat_field_name'][0][0].dtype.name
```

returns a `**uint8_t**` instead of `**double**`.

A sample mat file can be generated with use of `randi` function. (Or I can provide with a test case)

Comment: I get 'float64' when I try to reproduce your example.

Comment: I used `randi`: `mat_struct_name`[`mat_field_name`]  = randi([-5, 5], 5,1) and version of matlab is 17a